# Android Studio - Errores en archivo SQLiteDatabase.java (que nunca toqué)

Tags: android-studio, sqlite

Tengo 125 errores en un archivo "SQLiteDatabase.java" que nunca toqué.
Todos los errores son de tipo "cannot resolve simbol xxx"

[image: captura de algunos errores]

Pareciera ser una cuestión de SDK, pero he descargado e instalado los últimos 3 SDK y no pasa nada. los errores siguen ahí.
Los errores saltaron al hacer un debugueo. Jamás había tocado el archivo en cuestión.

También probé revertir el proyecto a versiones anteriores que funcionaban, pero los errores siguen estando.
Por otro lado, en otros proyectos no estoy teniendo problemas. (Aunque ni siquiera encuentro el archivo SQLiteDatabase.java)

Se agradece cualquier idea para probar.

Answer (score 0):

al final quedó "solucionado". Desinstalé los sdk y volví a instalar el 9.0 (pie).
Al debuguear la app de nuevo, me tiró la siguiente advertencia:

[image: imagen con la advertencia]

Si le doy Download y refresh al segundo cartelito, me vuelve a tirar todos los errores que tenía al abrir este hilo. Ocurre lo mismo si descargo los recursos de android 10.0 desde el sdk managger (sources for android 29, o sources for android 30. Estos corresponden al sdk 10.0(Q) y 10.0+(R) respectivamente y son visibles al tildar la opcion "show packages details en la esquina inferior derecha del sdk manager)

Asi que bueno, por ahora trabajaré con el sdk 9.0(pie).

Si alguien sabe cuál es el problema les agradecería muchísimo si me lo explican. Saludos!!